# How to run a python script when a hyperlink is clicked from a webpage?

Tags: html, database, python-3.x, web

I have some code on my mac in the latest version of python idle 3, that collects certain data from a csv file that gets sent to myself and prints out the output in the terminal. I want to create a webpage that has a button or link that a user clicks and it runs the code and prints out the output of my program.

Eventually i want to be able to create a website with multiple links that can do the same operation.

Will i need to create an sql database? If so how?...

Answer (score 0):

From the sound of it, you want to use a webpage as a user interface for your python script. Unfortunately without utilising a server-side language this is not possible.

Multiple options exist for reacting to a button press on the server side, with PHP being the most well known, but solutions using only python do exist, such as Flask.

If you're just after a local GUI for your script, simpler options exist within python such as Tk.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can expose this function using a webserver and then the webpage will call the server with the right url.
Since you are using python I will recommend  to take a look at Flask http://flask.pocoo.org/ great micro framework to get you started.